# Float:left - Float:right Issue when div is too high. (Have the solution, but don't know how to implement it into MYSQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

so I'm currently extracting my rows from my table in my database: like so

```
$result_article = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY article_id DESC") or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");;
    while($row_article = $result_article->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo    '<div class="featured-news">
                    <div class="featured-news-header">
                        <p>'.date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row_article['article_date'])).'</p>
                        <h3>'.$row_article['article_title'].'</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-news-content">
                        <p>'.nl2br($row_article['article_content']).'</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-news-footer">
                        <a href="index.php?page=nyheder-edit&id='.$row_article['article_id'].'"><img height="30px" src="img/action_buttons/nyheder.png"></a>
                        <a onclick="return confirm(\'Er du sikker på at du vil slette dette produkt?\');" href="index.php?page=nyheder-delete&id='.$row_article['article_id'].'"><img height="30px" src="img/action_buttons/delete.png"></a>
                        <div class="clear-fix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }
?>
```

And here is my style:

```
.featured-news {
background-color:white;
margin-top:2%;
margin-left:2%;
border-radius:6px;
overflow:hidden;
width:49%;
float:right;
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.featured-news:hover {
transform:scale(1.01,1.01);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.featured-news:nth-of-type(1), .featured-news:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
margin-left:0;
float:left;
width:49%;
}
```

Okay.. So this is how it looks like when my divs are same height:

Exactly what I want... all though.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr2pZ.png

When I drag out my browser (height changes because of content strectches:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFpOa.png

I could easily fix this myself, if I wasn't extracting these divs, can't twist my head around to get it work, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using Masonry.js, which is really helpfull
http://masonry.desandro.com/